# Rendering Javascript via custom HTML Helper extension method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In our ASP.NET MVC3 project we have written couple of custom HTML Helper extension method, which basically renders some composit controls (say a text and a label with some needed styles). Now we also want to render some javascript along with HTML tags, but looks MVCHtmlString does not render javascript test as javascript ! Any options or alternatives to render dynamic javascript from custom HTML Helpers ?

Comment: Did you wrap it in script tags? Javascript won't be parsed unless wrapped

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works fine for me :)

here is what I used as an extension method:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensionMethods
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString SomeJavascript(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("<script> alert('testing 123')</script>");


            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

and in my index.cshtml i call it like this:

```
@using MvcApplication1.ExtensionMethods
....
@Html.SomeJavascript()
```

and it shows me the pop-up :)

Comment: Really ? Let me tray, one more time.

Comment: Yes, absolutely ! Thank you.

Comment: @AlexPeta When i googled this question i thought that i found nothing but this is really interesting :) Thank You!!!

Comment: Can we put jquery in this script tag?